# ASP.NET Core Web API Error: Model 1[TContext] violates the Constraint of type 'TContext'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Solution in Visual Studio 2017 that contains the following Projects:

CredentialManager.API (ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API project)

CredentialManager.Models (Class Library that contains the Domain Model and Data Context Class)

The Domain Model Class is coded as follows:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CredentialManager.Models.Entities
{
    public class Credential
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long CredentialId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Application { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Data Context Class is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using CredentialManager.Models.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CredentialManager.Models.Context
{
    public class CredentialManagerContext : DbContext
    {

        public CredentialManagerContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Credential> Credentials { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The appsettings.json file looks like the following:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "i.": null,
    "CredentialManagerDB": "server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=CredentialManagerDB;Trusted_Connection=true;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

The Startup.CS file looks like this:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddDbContext<CredentialManagerContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:CredentialManagerDB"]));

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }
```

I then build the Solution and Added Migrations. But when I run update-database, I get the following error:

```
GenericArguments[0], 'CredentialManager.Models.Migrations.CredentialManagerContext', on 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type 'TContext'.
```

Can someone here throw some light on this error ? If I include the classes and data context in the same folder as the API project, then everything works.. But I want these classes to be part of a separate Class Library Project. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What classes you want to move to separate project? `Credential` and `CredentialManagerContext `? Check that you have no other `Credential` class in your project

Comment: Yes - Credential and CredentiaManagerContext need to be in a separate Class Library Project. There are no other classes with the same names in the Project..

Comment: I take it you have 1 migration that successfully built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update context file to have the following:

```
public CredentialManagerContext(DbContextOptions<CredentialManagerContext> options)
     : base(options)
{ }
```

As outlined in the documentation:

> This requires adding a constructor argument to your DbContext type that accepts :

```
DbContextOptions<TContext>
```

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the suggestions. I found a Solution as well. The Startup.cs needs to be informed about the Project that contains the Migrations:

```
services.AddDbContext<CredManagerContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CredentialManagerDB"), x => x.MigrationsAssembly("CredManager.Models")));
```

Everything works perfectly after this.